# How do I enable Numpy on Google App Engine with Python38

Tags: python, numpy, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

How do I enable `numpy` on Google App Engine when using `runtime: python38`? I tried to add the following to my `app.yaml` file but it says I can only do it like this with `runtime: python27`:

```
- name: numpy
  version: "1.6.1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it to your `requirements.txt` file in the root of your project:

```
numpy==1.6.1
```